# Предкомпилированные заголовки Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, header

Веду большой проект на C++ в Visual Studio 2010 (чистый C++/WinAPI), и в последнее время появилась необходимость использования предкомпилированных заголовков.

Есть пара-тройка файлов, которые меняются редко (минимум раз в 4 дня или чаще) и включаются везде. При изменении их содержимого приходится перекомпилировать весь проект, что может занять на небыстрой машине минут 15.

При создании предкомпилированного заголовка я сталкиваюсь с другой проблемой - директива #include файла заголовка должна быть указана во всех файлах, существующих в проекте. Но мой проект содержит несколько библиотек с открытым кодом, содержимое файлов которых я менять не хочу из-за необходимости периодического обновления этих библиотек.

Поэтому я получаю ошибки **C1010: непредвиденный конец файла во время поиска предкомпилированного заголовка. Возможно, вы забыли добавить директиву "'#include name'" в источник**.

Возможно, есть способ указать среде, что мой файл предкомпилированного заголовка должен включаться во все файлы по умолчанию автоматически? Есть ли способ использовать предкомпилированные заголовки в моем случае?

Comment: Не понял. Вы говорите, что используете посторонние библиотеки. Но что вам мешает вообще выключить использование предкомпилированных заголовков именно там?

Answer (score 1):

> Можно не прописывать во все файлы #include «stdafx.h», а
>   воспользоваться механизмом «Forced Included File».
>
> Идём на вкладку настроек «Advanced». Выбираем все конфигурации. В поле
>   «Forced Included File» пишем:
>
> StdAfx.h;%(ForcedIncludeFiles)
>
> Теперь «stdafx.h» автоматически будет включаться в начало ВСЕХ
>   компилируемых файлов. PROFIT!
>
> Больше не потребуется писать #include «stdafx.h» в начале всех
>   *.c/*.cpp файлов. Компилятор сделает это сам.

Взято отсюда https://habr.com/company/pvs-studio/blog/227521/

Answer (score 0):

> директива #include файла заголовка должна быть указана во всех файлах, существующих в проекте.

Нет, такая директива `#include` должна быть указана только в тех файлах, для которых включена установка "Использовать предкомпилированные заголовки". Эта установка контролируется с точностью до индивидуального файла. Если у вас есть файлы (или проекты), в которые вы по какой-то причине не хотите включать эту директиву `#include` - просто индивидуально для них выключите использование предкомпилированных заголовков.

Не совсем понимаю ваше упоминание посторонних библиотек. Посторонние библиотеки вами не модифицируются, от ваших заголовков не зависят, по каковой причине компилируются только один раз и частой перекомпиляции не требуют. Соответственно, для них нет смысла использовать предкомпилированные заголовки. Просто выключите для них использование предкомпилированных заголовков и все.